# Why does presentViewController not work?

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, presentviewcontroller

I have created a new project to experiment MultipeerConnectivity. I added these lines to present a viewcontroller in viewDidLoad, but it not comes up. Why? Only a white background I can see.

```
MCBrowserViewController *browserViewController =
[[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithBrowser:browser
                                         session:session];
browserViewController.delegate = self;

self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

[self presentViewController:browserViewController animated:YES completion:
 ^{
     [browser startBrowsingForPeers];
 }];
```

**UPDATE:**

I see this in the console:

Warning: Attempt to present MCBrowserViewController: whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Yes, You may have MCBrowserViewController with white background color. Just try to set the MCBrowserViewController's view with redColor and check whether it is presented or not.

Comment: Also if you want to see the presenting animation, you should present your controller in viewDidAppear instead if viewDidLoad.

Comment: good idea, I set it to red, but background is still white

Comment: you may have a view controller over source view controller. Please provide your view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling this in `viewDidLoad`. At that point the view is created but it's not visible anywhere, which means that the view controller has not yet appeared. You need to perform this method on `viewDidAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something in the view controllers' initialization. Do you properly instantiate a view hierarchy for the view controller? What does it mean "but it not comes up".
Can you only see a white background of the presenting view controller or of the presented view Controller? Try to set a breakpoint in the completion block. Is browser defined? Does the completion callback even get called?

Comment: Where should I add the view of the MCBrowserViewController as subview?

Comment: completion will not get called

Comment: Read in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html "Subclassing Notes" and view management, you are missing a view instantiation.